# Тестирование. Как отменить запись в БД при прогоне теста? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testng

При прогоне тестов (CRUD) нужно удалять (или отменять) запись в БД, что бы не лезть руками каждый раз в тест и не переписывать `id` для
всех методов.

рассматриваю следующий метод:

```
  DB::table('table_name')->truncate();
```

Идеальный вариант для теста: не делает инкремент для `id`, но как прописать его в "рабочий" контроллер, где уже есть метод `->delete();` - который делает автоинкремент для "рабочей" версии.

Кроме как сделать "перегруженный" контроллер, больше версий не вижу.

Comment: Использовать Mock  ?

Comment: @zalex, mock возвращает то, что было прописано в самом тесте? Если ошибаюсь - прошу прощения. 

Если не ошибаюсь, то  мне это не поможет протестить запись в БД?

Comment: Все верно, я не правильно понял что именно вам нужно сделать.